# Associative array of EmbedMany documents in Doctrine ODM

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to create an associative array of embedMany relationship with string keys for example
 I have a Document class named `sampleDocument` and it has a n EmbedMany relationship on the field `price`.

this is how I am setting the price field with associative array with string keys:

```
$obj->setPrice(array('key1' => $priceObjOne, 'key2' => $priceObj2));
```

it insert that data into the mongo as follows:

```
{
  "prices": [
     {/*Price Object*/}, { /*Price Object*/ }
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to do is to have a string key for each one. it  already has the string key in the array. but it doesn't insert it into the Mongo. 
how can I get passed it?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for your issue? I am getting exactly the same problem. Using @Hash is not suited as the object part is lost when retrieving documents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "prices" as @Hash type in your object.
With “type” attribute set to “hash”, Doctrine will store and retrieve the value as an associative array:

```
<?php
class SampleDocument
{
    /** @Hash */
    protected $prices = array();
}
```

Comment: already tried that.. i'm getting a mongo error when setting it as Hash and trying to insert array of EmbeddedDocuments (Objects).. 

thats the Error i'm getting by the way:   `[MongoException]                                                     
  zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?`

Comment: Seems this will not work if you don't define each price element as object as well, which is not applicable to your schema 'key'->object. You can try with the raw update query: $dm->createQueryBuilder('Collection_name')
    ->update()
    ->field('prices')->pushAll(array('key1' => $priceObjOne, 'key2' => $priceObj2))
    ->field('id')->equals(obj->getId())
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();